# Excel VBA: How to get Boolean from cell?

Tags: excel, vba

I have cell with `boolean` value (formatted as `General`). Code below throws `Run-time error '13': Type mismatch`

```vb
Dim bVar As Boolean 
bVar = Selection.Value
```

What I'm doing wrong?

```vb
Debug.Print TypeName(Selection.Value)
```

Returns `"String"`

Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: Try, please: `bVar = CBool(Selection.Value)`. You can check it in this way: `Debug.Print TypeName(CBool(Selection.Value))`.

Comment: Could you share the whole code, so we could see in which context this is happening, because I can't reproduce it. No matter if `TRUE` (when `TypeName(Selection.Value)` returns `Boolean`) or `="True"` (when `TypeName(Selection.Value)` returns `String`) are in the cell, there is no error. There should be no need for `CBool`.

Comment: It was in context of `ListObject Table` there was Loop like: `For i = 1 to Table.ListRows("A").Rows ` `bVar = Table.ListColumns("A").Range.Rows(i).Value`

Comment: @VBasic2008: You are right. I tried answering only to convert a String to Boolean... But, if `bVar` has been declared as `Boolean` the conversion is done automatically. Of course, if selection refers to a single cell having strings like "True", "False" or numbers (for 0 returns `False` and `True` for everything bigger then 0). The above error may occur only if no such a string is kept in the selection value, or selection contains more then one cell... But, if the string is not "True" or "False", even if it is the equivalent in the localization language, it may return that error.

Comment: What specific strings are in the processed range? Something else than "True", "False" or numbers? If yes, this is the reason of the error... "Dog" cannot be converted to `Boolean`...

Comment: @Lluser: Without the code there is little to do. You can edit your question at any time with the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63737572/edit) button below your post. The code you posted in the comments didn't work for me. I would suggest you try the following: `For i = 1 To Table.ListRows.Count` and  `bVar = Table.ListRows(i).Range.Columns(1).Value`, if the boolean values are in the **1**st column of `Table`. If not, change the `1` referring to `Columns` accordingly.